# Why my transformers model is getting nan loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

So i have this code that is an ASR using transformers https://www.kaggle.com/code/bernardoolisan/speechrecognition-dot, the problem is that I was using a dataset of 25 hours of audio, the ASR works but when using new data it sucks, this is because of 25 hours, at least you should use 100 up hours for training.

So I decided to use LibriSpeech dataset that contains 1000, 360, 100 hours for training, the thing is that when I use libriSpeech when training I get

```
loss:nan
```

[Picture of loss:nan when training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zfrc.png)

Why am I getting loss:nan? it was working with the old dataset but now is not, and I did not change any parameter...

Any idea?

Comment: promover la integración familiar

Comment: promover la seguridad

Comment: promover el cuidado de los animales en peligro de extinción

Comment: promover el respeto a la dignidad de las personas

Comment: promover la inclusión efectiva de personas vulnerables